# Image Alt Text not shown in DXA Website

Tags: dxa

I have added alternate text metadata on images in the CMS for an out-of-the-box DXA 1.0 (.NET) website and republished the pages, but the alt text is not showing. Where is this data getting lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the schema XML field name (`altText`), and the `Image.AlternateText` property semantic mapping.

The non-code way to fix this is to update the XML field name to be `alternateText`, which will mean there is an automatic mapping to the `AlternateText` property. However be aware that renaming a schema field will remove any existing metadata in components using that schema.

This can also be fixed in code, by simply adding an appropriate mapping to the `Image.AlternateText` property:

```
[SemanticProperty("s:name")]
[SemanticProperty("altText")]
public string AlternateText { get; set; }
```